# sort elements in Isotope container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

On [this page](http://festivals.jelastic.com/festival/show/3), I'm using the jQuery Isotope plugin to layout the artists in a festival's lineup. I want the artists to be sorted by their performance date. I've followed [the instructions](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html) and added `sortBy` and `getSortDate` properties to the Isotope options object. The code (in `common.js`) that creates the Isotope container is:

```
var container = $(containerSelector);

var isotopeOptions = {
    itemSelector: itemSelector,
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    onLayout: function() {
        this.css('visibility', 'visible');
    },

    getSortData: {
        perfDate: function (element) {

            // parse out the performance date from the css classes
            var classList = element.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
            var dateClassPrefix = 'date-';

            $.each(classList, function(index, cssClassName){

                if (cssClassName.substring(0, dateClassPrefix.length) === dateClassPrefix) {

                    // Should be a date in format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                    var dateString = cssClassName.substring(dateClassPrefix.length);
                    return SF.parseDate(dateString).getTime();
                }
            });
        }
    },
    sortBy: 'perfDate'
};

container.imagesLoaded(function() {
    container.isotope(isotopeOptions);
});
```

As you can see the artists are not sorted by performance date. I've debugged into my sorting function and verified that it returns the following values

- B.o.B (15 April) => 1334444400000
- Bob Marley (20 April) => 1334876400000
- Bob Dylan (26 April) => 1335394800000

So the artists should be displayed in the order above. Curiously, if I replace my sorting function with one that sorts the artists alphabetically by name, e.g.

```
perfDate: function (element) {
    return element.find('.artistTitle a').text();
},
```

Then the artists are displayed in the same order as the values returned by the sorting function. Why does sorting by name work, but sorting by performance date doesn't?

Answer (score -1):

You can check to see what values were set for the sortData like so:

```
$('#headline').data('isotope').$filteredAtoms.each( function( i, item ) {
  console.log( $.data( item, 'isotope-sort-data').perfDate );
});
```

In your case, this returns `undefined` for all three elements.

The problem looks to be that the `return` with `$.each` ends the each `function`, but it doesn't return the date value. You can resolve this by getting the date within `$.each` and returning that at the end of `perfDate` function.

```
perfDate: function (element) {

  // parse out the performance date from the css classes
  var classList = element.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  var dateClassPrefix = 'date-';

  var date;

  $.each(classList, function(index, cssClassName){

    if (cssClassName.substring(0, dateClassPrefix.length) === dateClassPrefix) {

      // Should be a date in format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
      var dateString = cssClassName.substring(dateClassPrefix.length);
      date = SF.parseDate(dateString).getTime();
    }
  });
  return date;
}
```